# How to implement a copy constructor of the derived class on a vector of pointers to base class which has instances of derived classes?

Tags: c++

So I have a base class Furniture which is also an abstract class, and derived classes Bed, Table, Chair, and Desk. I am using a vector of pointers to the base class Furniture and in there i hold instances of the derived classes. I have another class cash register which performs operations with the furniture vector. I have to use a copy constructor of the derived classes which i have made, and the idea with this snippet of code is for me to clone the derived class object which is held in the vector of pointers in the base class, in the safest way possible.
So these are my copy constructors:

```
explicit Desk(const Desk& _desk) : Furniture(_desk),     numberOfDrawers(_desk.numberOfDrawers) {};
explicit Table(const Table& _table) : Furniture(_table), numberOfLegs(_table.numberOfLegs) {};
explicit Chair(const Chair& _chair) : Furniture(_chair), numberOfLegs(_chair.numberOfLegs) {};
explicit Bed(const Bed& _bed) : Furniture(_bed), size(_bed.size) {};
```

And the way that i have thought of so far is:

```
std::cout << "The object is found: " << furniture[index]->getName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Price:               " << furniture[index]->getPrice() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Code:                " << furniture[index]->getCode() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Do you want to copy the purchase of " << furniture[index]->getName() << " ? (Y/N)";
    char read;
    std::cin >> read;
    if (read == 'Y')
    {
        if (furniture[index]->getName() == "Bed") {

            Bed* deskClone = new Bed(dynamic_cast<Bed&>(*furniture[index]));
            furniture.push_back(deskClone);
        }
        if (furniture[index]->getName() == "Desk") {
            Desk* bedClone = new Desk(dynamic_cast<Desk&>(*furniture[index]));
            furniture.push_back(bedClone);
        }
        if (furniture[index]->getName() == "Table") {
            Table* tableClone = new Table(dynamic_cast<Table&>(*furniture[index]));
            furniture.push_back(tableClone);
        }
        if (furniture[index]->getName() == "Chair") {
            Chair* chairClone = new Chair(dynamic_cast<Chair&>(*furniture[index]));
            furniture.push_back(chairClone);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I read that this is dangerous, so I wanted to ask if there is a better way to go about this? 
BTW: this is my first post guys don't be too mean :D

Comment: By switching on a type descriptor you single-handedly defeat the work of generations of computer scientists who have invented, implemented, promoted, and brought to damn near perfection the field of object oriented programming. Please use `virtual Furniture* clone()`.

Comment: Could you make a method in the base class which all children implements which is called e.g. make_copy(), which creates a copy? And I would recommend using shared_ptr's

Answer (score 0):

Add a pure virtual cloning function to the base class, override everywhere, and replace the entire conditional soup with

```
furniture.push_back(furniture[index]->clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, make a virtual function in the base class

```
virtual Furniture* copy() = 0;
```

which the children implements

```
class Bed
{
    ...
    virtual Furniture* copy() override
    {
       return new Bed(*this);
    }
    ...
};
```